# Which room gets entered in the contest?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

I've noticed that there appears to be very few room submitted that follow the theme of the contest. And I was beginning to wonder if maybe the problem is that the game submits the main room and not the current room you've opened. Like I use one of the other rooms to set up for theme challenges so I don't have to rearrange my main room. And I hit submit while in the room I've decked out.

The game doesn't actually tell you which room gets submitted or any other kind of guide lines. I've tried emailing support about it but no one's gotten back to me yet.

Answer (score 1):

The room that you are currently in is the one that will be published for the online room challenges. More likely than not as you browse through other people's rooms published for a certain theme, you will notice that they don't particularly follow the trend. This may be for multiple reasons. It may be that they are a relatively low level player, and hence won't have many items matching to the theme. Another reason may be that they became confused about which room they were in whilst publishing, or assumed that when they click publish it will let them select a room to publish then.